# Getting error message handling the json object in java

Tags: java, json, .net

**strong text**

error msg:
constructor jsonobject in class jsonobject cannot be applied to given types
required: no arguments
found: string
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I've downloaded the jar file and included it in my netbeans ide,but couldn’t get through this error.

I've downloaded the json jar 2.8.2 file, if it was not okay, providing the link of the actual jar file would be beneficial.If the problem is not with the jar file then what is it?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Edit your question adding your code

Answer (score 0):

Add some code to figure out the issue
and probably you are importing wrong package
try to use this one : "org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"